# Galois group of $f := X^6 - 6 ∈ \Bbb Q[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

A quick sanity check:

A splitting field for $f$ over $\Bbb Q$ is $L := \Bbb Q(\zeta_3, \sqrt[6]{6})$. It is of degree 12 over $\Bbb Q$, so Gal$(f)$ will be a group of order 12. An automorphism of $L$ must send $\sqrt[6]{6}$ to $± \zeta_3^k \sqrt[6]{6}$ for some $k ∈ \{0,1,2\}$, but it must also send $\zeta_3 $ to $\zeta_3^k $. Does this provide enough information to determine the Galois group?

Comment: Not the same $k$.

Comment: Imagine those six roots on the complex plane. They form a regular hexagon, right? If $\tau:\zeta_6\mapsto \zeta_6$, then $\tau$ must rotate the vertices of the hexagon because the image of the next zero depends on that of the previous: $\tau(x\zeta_6)=\tau(x)\zeta_6.$ On the other hand, if $\tau:\zeta_6\mapsto \overline{\zeta_6}$, then the order of rotation is reversed: $\tau(x\zeta_6)=\tau(x)\overline{\zeta_6}$.  Therefore....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think rather than $\zeta_3$ a root of $X^2 + X + 1$ you need $\zeta_6$ a root of $X^2 - X + 1$.

You will have the complex conjugation automorphism $\tau$.

And 6 different maps $\sigma \sqrt[6]{6} = \zeta_6^r \sqrt[6]{6}$ for $r$ being $1$ up to $6$.

The complex conjugation $\tau$ map interacts with the $\sigma$ maps by reversing the cycle, similar to the dihedral group.

Comment: That's all there is to it :-)

Comment: Thanks, but why go to ζ₆? And what does $X² - X + 1$ have to do with it?

Comment: Ah, I was not familiar with the $n^{\text{th}}$ cyclotomic polynomial, ($n$ not prime)